# Show and hide button below appbar or toolbar when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to show a button below the appbar whenever content (`fragment_container`) is scrolled in a `CoordinatorLayout`. It sort of works, but I want the button to show just below the `appbar/toolbar` as opposed to expand the height of the appbar when showing. It currently expands the appbar, because it's nested within it. I've tried combinations with a `RelativeLayout` without any luck.

How do I "detach" it from the `appbar/toolbar` and still make it appear below, when the content is scrolled?

On the image below, green is denoting the appbar, purple the `toolbar` and red the button that I want to show outside (directly below) the `appbar/toolbar` layouts. The white background shows a recyclerview within the `fragment_container`.

[image: Current layout]

The layout used to obtain the results in the image above:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/coordinator">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar">

      <Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/scrollToTop"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

See the image below for the result I'm after. When scrolling down content in the CoordinatorLayout I want the button to appear. Scrolling up (swiping up) should remove the button.

[image: Desired layout]

Answer (score 1):

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout); 
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG); View view = snackbar.getView();   
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();    
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params); snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Not what I want. Your example shows a SnackBar at the very top of the CoordinatorLayout. I want to show a view below the appbar and make it appear and disappear when the CoordinatorLayout is moving. It needs to be "outside" and below the AppBarLayout within the CoordinatorLayout.